# How to sort number in a <textarea> separated by comma in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, input, numbers

I have a simple textarea which I input somthing like: 1,7,5,2,30
then I put the numbers in Array,when I try to sort the Array ,it actually separate 30 into "3" and "0".and give me result of : 0,1,2,3,5,7 .
what I want is: 1,2,5,7,30 .how to solve this?
Thanks.

here is the Code:

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");

var array=[];
var sortedArray=[];

var i=j=len=0;

myButton.onclick = function () {
myFunc(); 
}

function myFunc() {
array = textArea.value;

for(i=0,len=array.length ; i<len ; i++) {
    if(array[i] != ",") {
        sortedArray[j] = array[i];
        ++j;
    }
}

console.log( sortedArray.sort(function (a,b) {
    return a-b;
    }) ); 
}
```

Comment: show your code. May be a fiddle?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code snippets you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s how I’d solve it:

```
var textArea, myButton;

textArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myButton.onclick = function () {
    console.log(myFunc());
}

function myFunc() {
    var values, sorted, i;

    values = textArea.value.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        values[i] = parseInt(values[i], 10);
    }

    sorted = values.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a-b;
    });

    return sorted;
}
```

Explanation of `myFunc`:

- The textarea’s value is converted to an array using the `split` method
- The values are converted to integers so they can be sorted in a meaningful way
- The values are sorted using a custom sort function (the default sort algorithm is only suitable for sorting strings)

Comment: Thanks aaronk6,I totally forgot to use split() .then again no need for parsInt ,after using array.split we can sort() the numbers :)

Comment: It’s safer not to rely on implicit conversion. If you want to perform arithmetic operations on a value, make sure it’s a number, not a string. Otherwise, unexpected things may happen. There’s a funny talk on this topic: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat